# Scheduled c# console app on windows server does not show console when ran from task scheduler

Tags: c#, console, scheduled-tasks

The title basically states my problem. I have a c# console app that I am scheduling in windows server 2003 that when ran from the task scheduler does not show the console window.

I want it to show the console window. If I double click my exe it will show the console window. I am confused.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The task is likely scheduled to run the console app under a different user account.

Comment: I verified I am using the same account.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the "Task Scheduler" service has "Allow service to interact with desktop" checked.  That is the underlying service that Windows uses to invoke scheduled tasks.  If it is not setup to allow desktop interaction your scheduled tasks will not be allowed access either.

Comment: found it, checked it. restarted the service and no go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark run only when logged on General tab.